# How to cross-compile the WebKit Gtk for ARM?

Tags: webkit, cross-compiling

I want to cross-compile the WebKit Gtk(recent revision 174059) for ARM architecture.
I searched the way for it in official web site(trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingGtk) and google search, but i couldn't find the way.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and already built WebKit Gtk in x86 architecture successfulㅣy .
so I considered using the cross-compile tools like 'scratchbox', but it was very complex jobs and didn't work well. because Webkit needs many uninstalled libraries and it's build system also uses 'jhbuild'.

is there any simple way to cross-compile WebKit Gtk for ARM?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sure about cross compile, but you can try qEMU emulator of ARM CPU and up&run *Stretch armhf* release of Debian.

**PS** 
Unfortunately qEMU is unbearable slow, so it will require a HUGE amount of time to install all dependancies and build WebKit. 
In my case I've bought used ChromeBook with ARM and run there Debian over crouton, it saved me a lot of time to build WebKit GTK+